# Android compile library error

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I'm try using library NCHART3D

My `build.gradle`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.test3dchart"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile files('libs/NChart3D.jar')
}
```

and logcat print :

```
Couldn't load nchart3d from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.test3dchart-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.android.test3dchart-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null

01-15 13:29:50.177    2793-2793/com.example.android.chart D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
01-15 13:29:50.267    2793-2793/com.example.android.chart W/dalvikvm﹕ Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/nulana/NChart/NChartView;
01-15 13:29:50.267    2793-2793/com.example.android.chart W/dalvikvm﹕ Class init failed in Constructor.constructNative (Lcom/nulana/NChart/NChartView;)
01-15 13:29:50.267    2793-2793/com.example.android.chart D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
01-15 13:29:50.267    2793-2793/com.example.android.chart W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415778b0)
01-15 13:29:50.277    2793-2793/com.example.android.chart E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

**UPDATE**
in xml preview

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <com.nulana.NChart.NChartView
        android:id="@+id/surface"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Rendering Problems The following classes could not be found:
- com.nulana.NChart.NChartView (Fix Build Path, Create Class)
 Tip: Try to build the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this because of redundancy, in following code first line already including your jar.

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile files('libs/NChart3D.jar')
```

try to remove compile files('libs/NChart3D.jar'), then clean project and rebuild

make sure you have following project structure, and note that your jar should go into libs folder and other lib components in jniLibs. This is for android studio 1.0

[image: project tree]

Comment: im try :  dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
} no working :/

Comment: @Luis my guess is that you have not correct project structure. I downloaded NChart3D lib and tried one of demo projects and it worked without any error or warring. I updated my answer , checkout picture and make sure you have correct project structure